# Using inclued php pecl extension

Tags: php, debugging, pecl, inclued

I'm currently trying to level up on my PHP debugging skills and as part of that I'm trying to learn several new tools. One of them is [inclued](http://pecl.php.net/package/inclued).

The extension seemingly works fine (no startup error, shows up in phpinfo, generates dump files), but it always reports number of includes as 0, so something is clearly not working right.

At first I suspected this was related to my heavy use of `auto_include`, but after doing some tests which do not, I doubt that is related.

Class graphs are generated OK, but include maps simply don't exist. Am I simply Doing It Wrong, or is the extension broken? I just don't know and even after some heavy duty googling cannot find anything useful.

I installed `inclued` using the "`phpize` method". My PHP version is 5.3.2 running on Mac OSX 10.6.5. I also have XDebug and memtrack installed.

Comment: I nearly edited this post to fix the spelling of 'include' :)

Comment: I know. Google does that and it's really frustrating. (But apparently its supposed to give you a clue about your includes ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing a test run with valgrind watching Apache I noticed xdebug was operating below inclued. On a blind test I tried disabling XDebug and lo and behold: inclued works as expected.

So to answer my own question:

Don't use XDebug in conjunction with inclued if you want to have include graphs. Class graphing works fine with XDebug running.